# How setting default value with code first migration C# for Database

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

my question is really simple... Is it possible, with code first migration and C#, to put default value like country or tag or state when generating a new database from scratch with the tool? If yes, would you explain me how please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could either run raw SQL in your migration to insert your data:

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.Sql("INSERT ...");
    }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can get access to your context after the last migration has run and you can insert your data there:

```
public sealed class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
   public MyConfiguration()
   {
       this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
   }

   protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
   {
       context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Id, this.GetMyUsers());
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use raw sql in the Seed method to do this. AddOrUpdate didn't work for my scenario so I ended up doing this:

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator(OracleConnectionInfo.InvariantName, new OracleEntityMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        Logger.Write("In Seed method. User: " + userName);
        MyInitializer.AddUpdateDataSql(context);
    }
}

public class MyInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>
{
    private const string Schemaname = "MYSCHEMA";

    public static void AddUpdateDataSql(Pronova2Context context)
    {
        DeleteTableData(context);
        DropCreateSequences(context);
        PopulateTypeTypeData(context);
        // etc.
    }

    private static void DeleteTableData(DbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete " + Schemaname + ".T_TABLE1"); }
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete " + Schemaname + ". T_TABLE2"); }
        // etc.
    }

    private static void DropCreateSequences(DbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"DROP SEQUENCE  " + Schemaname + ".T_TABLE1_SEQ"); }
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"DROP SEQUENCE  " + Schemaname + ".T_TABLE2_SEQ"); }
        // etc.
    }

    private static void PopulateTypeTypeData(DbContext context)
    {
        try { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Insert into " + Schemaname + ".T_TYPE_TYPE (TYPE_TYPE_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION) values (1,'TypeType1','Name 1')");
        try { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Insert into " + Schemaname + ".T_TYPE_TYPE (TYPE_TYPE_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION) values (2,'TypeType1','Name 2')");
        // etc.
    }
}
```